# Google Dataflow flex-template run results in INVALID_ARGUMENT error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to deploy a Java dataflow job to Google dataflow based on a custom pubsub-to-elasticsearch template.

Why is it that this CLI call is successful...

```
    --update \
    --region us-central1 \
    --worker-machine-type=n1-standard-2 \
    --service-account-email="<redacted>" \
    --template-file-gcs-location "gs://<redacted>/pubsub-to-elasticsearch-template/v2.2.0/pubsub-elasticsearch-manifest.json" \
    --parameters projectId="<redacted>" \
    --parameters inputSubscription="projects/<redacted>/subscriptions/listsearch-order-events-processor" \
    --parameters errorOutputTopic="projects/<redacted>/topics/listsearch-order-events-processor-dead-letter" \
    --parameters connectionUrl="<redacted>" \
    --parameters withPartialUpdateFlag=true \
    --parameters apiKeySecret="secret-key" \
    --parameters index="my-index"
```

but when I add --enable-streaming-engine, I get INVALID_ARGUMENT?

```
    --update \
    --enable-streaming-engine \
    --region us-central1 \
    --worker-machine-type=n1-standard-2 \
    --service-account-email="<redacted>" \
    --template-file-gcs-location "gs://<redacted>/pubsub-to-elasticsearch-template/v2.2.0/pubsub-elasticsearch-manifest.json" \
    --parameters projectId="<redacted>" \
    --parameters inputSubscription="projects/<redacted>/subscriptions/listsearch-order-events-processor" \
    --parameters errorOutputTopic="projects/<redacted>/topics/listsearch-order-events-processor-dead-letter" \
    --parameters connectionUrl="<redacted>" \
    --parameters withPartialUpdateFlag=true \
    --parameters apiKeySecret="secret-key" \
    --parameters index="my-index"
```

I am using Google Dataflow, Java, and Apache Beam 2.49.0 (this worked fine with 2.41.0 but we are trying to upgrade)

Is there a best practice around using CLI parameters, i.e. when to use quotes, what orders the parameters need to be in, etc?

I've actually tried a variety of different parameters and orders, putting some quotes around argument values and not others, and getting both "INVALID_ARGUMENT" and "INVALID_PARAM" errors.

Is there a way to identify which parameter is the invalid one?

Thanks in advance.